# Small part of loop invariant i'm not getting

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Show that $y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$ is a loop invariant for the following WHILE loop:

y := 0;
z := 0
WHILE $\neg$(z = x) DO
  z := z + 1;
  y := y + z

In other words, proof that
$\{y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)\}$
z := z + 1;
y := y + z
$ \{y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)\}$

Used for this are the Hoare axioms:

H1 {[$t$\x]$\varphi$} x := $t$ {$\varphi$}, provided that $t$ is free for $x$ in $\varphi$
H2 from {$\varphi$} $\pi_1$ {$\psi$} and {$\psi$} $\pi_2$ {$\chi$} follows {$\varphi$} ($\pi_1;\pi_2$) {$\chi$}
H3 from {$\varphi \wedge \epsilon$} $\pi_1$ {$\psi$} and {$\varphi \wedge \neg \epsilon$} $\pi_2$ {$\psi$} follows {$\varphi$} IF $\epsilon$ THEN $\pi_1$ ELSE $\pi_2$ {$\psi$}
H4 from {$\varphi \wedge \epsilon$} $\pi$ {$\varphi$} follows {$\varphi$} WHILE $\epsilon$ DO $\pi$ {$\neg \epsilon \wedge \varphi$}
H5 if $\varphi \rightarrow \varphi`$ and $\psi \rightarrow \psi`$ are true in M = (**D**, I), then: from {$\varphi`$} $\pi$ {$\psi`$} follows {$\varphi$} $\pi$ {$\psi$}

1 {$y + z = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$}  y := y + z  {$y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$}   **H1**
2 {$y + (z + 1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (z + 1) \cdot ((z + 1) + 1)$}  z := z + 1   {$y + z = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$}   **H1**
3 {$y + (z + 1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (z + 1) \cdot (z + 2)$}

    z := z + 1

   {$y + z = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$}   **H5, 2**
4 {$y + (z + 1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (z + 1) \cdot (z + 2)$}
    z := z + 1; y := y + z
    {$y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$}   **H2, 3, 1**
5 {$y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$}
   z := z + 1; y := y + z
   {$y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$}   **H5, 4***

*This application of **H5** is correct because:
$y + (z + 1)$
$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot (z + 1) \cdot (z + 2)$
$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot (z + 1)$
$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1) + (z + 1)$

So the precondition in stap 3 is equivalent with $y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$.

It's this last part I'm not getting at all; how is the precondition {$y + (z + 1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (z + 1) \cdot (z + 2)$} equivalent with $y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$? What happens in this here equation that shows us that this is correct?

$y + (z + 1)$
$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot (z + 1) \cdot (z + 2)$
$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot (z + 1)$
$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1) + (z + 1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not sure to understand your question ...*

**If** we have :

> $y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$

then, adding $(z+1)$ to both sides, we get :

> $y +(z + 1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1) + (z+1) = \frac{1}{2}[ z \cdot (z + 1) + 2 \cdot (z+1)] = \frac{1}{2}[ (z + 2) \cdot (z+1)] $;

it's all ...

In your calculation you have :

$y + (z + 1)$
$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot (z + 1) \cdot (z + 2)$
$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot (z + 1)$
$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1) + (z + 1)$

and it's the same thing.

Having derived that :

> $y + (z + 1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1) + (z + 1)$

you "cancel" $(z+1)$ form both "sides" to get :

> $y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot z \cdot (z + 1)$.

Comment: Jeez... I guess it's time for vacation :-)

Comment: Wait, I know what I didn't get; how is it possible that the invariant with the $y + (z + 1)$ can be weakened to the one with just the $y$? In other words, how's it possible that the precondition on 4 and 5 changes, while the post condition stays the same.

Comment: @GarthMarenghi - I have still problem to understand the question... If the above are *algebraic* formulas, the "usual" algebraic rules must apply. What is $z := z + 1; y := y + z$ ? is a sort of "computing instruction" ? If so, if you "increase by one" the "variable" $z$ (see "instruction" $z := z + 1$) and then "update" the variable $y$ to $y+z$, the result will be $y + (z+1)$ equal to the old value of $y$ (which is $1/2⋅z⋅(z+1)$) plus $(z+1)$, so that ...

Comment: Yes, it is a computing construction, the innards of a while loop. With the help of Hoare-calculus, and an invariant, you can see if certain pieces of code are correct. In this case, if the while loop is correct.